# Can a self-supported finance student in Japan earn schoolarships, other than MEXT?

Tags: graduate-school, funding, japan

I've been looking into LLM programs in Japan. As far as I know, an international student can apply for the MEXT scholarship or as a self-supported finance student. I don't believe I can compete with all of the other students who apply for MEXT, so I believe it is a better idea to be a self-supported finance student.

Are there options for finding funding in Japan, other than MEXT? I did find [this](https://www.isc.kyushu-u.ac.jp/intlweb/scholarship/view/list.php?nendo=2022&lang=en) link, but I'm not sure if a self-supported student can apply for those.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Note, we will not be able to advise on Kyushu specifically (among other reasons, it's highly unlikely that anyone here has studied there). But your general question is interesting, I suggested an edit to increase your odds of getting an answer.

Comment: The link specifically says: "The following information is for the self-supporting international students." So it seems like you're already looking in the right place. Also: is LLM a law degree? If so, I trust you've already thought through the implications of this (e.g., a law degree from Japan probably won't be useful unless you stay in Japan long term).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I had not noticed this line.

Comment: Have you already read this document ("Scholarships for International Students in Japan")? [Study in Japan Website](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/en/planning/about-scholarship/) You can click on the image on the left side to download the PDF.